# Stacked count plot in seaborn

Tags: plot, seaborn, stacked

Is there a way of quickly creating a stacked **countplot**? I know I can create stacked **barplots** quite easily, but that requires the count values to be explicitly known. Is there a way of avoiding the extra step of counting?

Let's say I have a following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123,224,336,487,532,923, 987, 109, 289, 884], 
               'YOB':[1991, 1992, 1993, 1992, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1992], 
               'CoD':[1,1,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,1]})
```

and I want to obtain a stacked plot showing the count of CoD=1 against YOB, as a proportion of total.

[image: example plot]

Comment: According to [this link](http://randyzwitch.com/creating-stacked-bar-chart-seaborn/) the creator of seaborn is not a huge fan of stacked bar plots. Hence seaborn does not have any option for that. However there are ways to overcome this, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544694/using-pandas-crosstab-with-seaborn-stacked-barplots). In general, pandas provides the option to do stacked bars easily, so you just need to prepare your data accordingly.

Comment: Ah, crosstab :) Thank you! All sorted now.